# unable to query SQLite database with cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am pretty new to SQLite in android and I need an help.
I create an android project and I want to access do database using content provider. This is my code

the provider in the manifest file

```
<provider android:name="NaTempsProvider"
    android:authorities="com.sdnsoft.natemps.natemps.data.NaTempsProvider.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:enabled="true">
    <grant-uri-permission android:pathPattern=".*" />
</provider>
```

the contract

```
public class NaTempsContract {
public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.sdnsoft.natemps.natemps.data.NaTempsProvider.provider";// This class cannot be instantiated
private NaTempsContract() {
}

public static final class app_role implements BaseColumns {

    // This class cannot be instantiated
    private app_role() {
    }

    /**
     * The table name offered by this provider
     */
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "app_role";

    /*
     * URI definitions
     */

    /**
     * The scheme part for this provider's URI
     */
    private static final String SCHEME = "content://";


    /**
     * Path part for the app_role URI
     */
    private static final String PATH_APP_ROLE = "/app_role";

    /**
     * Path part for the app_role ID URI
     */
    private static final String PATH_APP_ROLE_ID = "/app_role/";

    /**
     * The content:// style URL for this table
     */
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(SCHEME + AUTHORITY + PATH_APP_ROLE);


    /**
     * The default sort order for this table
     */
    public static final String DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER = "name DESC";


    /*
     * Column definitions
     */

    /**
     * <P>Type: INTEGER</P>
     */
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ID = "id";

    /**
     * <P>Type: TEXT</P>
     */
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NAME = "name";

    /**
     * <P>Type: TEXT</P>
     */
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DISPLAY_NAME = "display_name";

}}
```

The provider

```
public class NaTempsProvider
    extends ContentProvider implements ContentProvider.PipeDataWriter<Cursor> {    // Used for debugging and loggingprivate static final String TAG = "NaTempsProvider";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


// Handle to a new DatabaseHelper.
private DatabaseHelper mOpenHelper;

static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        // calls the super constructor, requesting the default cursor factory.
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }    // all type into database

    public static final String PRIMARY_KEY_TYPE = " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ";
    // Structure de la table `app_role`

    public static final String APP_ROLE_TABLE_NAME = "app_role";
    public static final String APP_ROLE_PRIMARY_KEY = "id";

    public static final String APP_ROLE_NAME = "name";
    public static final String APP_ROLE_DISPLAY_NAME = "display_name";
    public static final String APP_ROLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + APP_ROLE_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    APP_ROLE_PRIMARY_KEY + PRIMARY_KEY_TYPE + "," +
                    APP_ROLE_NAME + " TEXT," +
                    APP_ROLE_DISPLAY_NAME +
                    " TEXT);INSERT INTO `app_role` (`id`, `name`, `display_name`) VALUES\n" +
                    "(1, 'accueil', 'Accueil'),\n" +
                    "(2, 'responsable_cercle', 'responsable de cercle');\n";


    public static final String APP_ROLE_TABLE_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + APP_ROLE_TABLE_NAME + ";";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(
                APP_ROLE_CREATE
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(
                APP_ROLE_TABLE_DROP
        );
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {

    // Creates a new helper object. Note that the database itself isn't opened until
    // something tries to access it, and it's only created if it doesn't already exist.
    mOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

    // Assumes that any failures will be reported by a thrown exception.
    return true;
}
...}
```

In my activity: on create

```
// If there is no data associated with the Intent, sets the data to the default URI, which
    // accesses a list of notes.
    if (intent.getData() == null) {
        intent.setData(NaTempsContract.app_role.CONTENT_URI);
    }

    /* Performs a managed query. The Activity handles closing and requerying the cursor
     * when needed.
     *
     * Please see the introductory note about performing provider operations on the UI thread.
     */
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
            getIntent().getData(),            // Use the default content URI for the provider.
            NaTempsProjections.APP_ROLE_PROJECTION,                       // Return the note ID and title for each note.
            null,                             // No where clause, return all records.
            null,                             // No where clause, therefore no where column values.
            null  // Use the default sort order.
    );
```

But when I run project, the cursor is null. And it's impossible to use data

Comment: first create table..then write a method to Insert data separately..

Comment: OK, I put query in another function, But nothing returned

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: Also remove Insert query from APP_ROLE_CREATE string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably related to/caused by the fact that  the `execSQL` method can only action a single SQL statement. As such you need to split the two SQL statements (the table creation and the data insertion) and then use the `execSQL` method twice e.g.

```
public static final String APP_ROLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + APP_ROLE_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    APP_ROLE_PRIMARY_KEY + PRIMARY_KEY_TYPE + "," +
                    APP_ROLE_NAME + " TEXT," +
                    APP_ROLE_DISPLAY_NAME +
                    " TEXT);";

public static final String APP_ROLE_INSERT = "INSERT INTO `app_role` (`id`, `name`, `display_name`) VALUES\n" +
                    "(1, 'accueil', 'Accueil'),\n" +
                    "(2, 'responsable_cercle', 'responsable de cercle');\n";

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(
                APP_ROLE_CREATE
        );
        db.execSQL(
                APP_ROLE_INSERT
        );
    }
```

using the following to test:-

```
Cursor csr = dbhlpr.getWritableDatabase().query(DatabaseHelper.APP_ROLE_TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        String logdata;
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            logdata = "Data in Row=" + csr.getPosition();
            for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                logdata = logdata +
                        "\n\t" + "Column Name=" + csr.getColumnName(i) +
                        " Value=" + csr.getString(i);
            }
            Log.d("ROWINFO",logdata);
        }
        csr.close();
```

results in :-

```
08-22 17:32:03.332 4103-4103/mjt.so45787986 D/ROWINFO: Data in Row=0
                                                        Column Name=id Value=1
                                                        Column Name=name Value=accueil
                                                        Column Name=display_name Value=Accueil
08-22 17:32:03.332 4103-4103/mjt.so45787986 D/ROWINFO: Data in Row=1
                                                        Column Name=id Value=2
                                                        Column Name=name Value=responsable_cercle
                                                        Column Name=display_name Value=responsable de cercle
```

I would suggest that you may need to either uninstall the App, delete the App's data or increase the version number, as the table may already have been created.

Alternately you could just run the second of the two i.e. (`db.execSQL(APP_ROLE_INSERT);`) on it's own. However, you may need to consider what the code for the final App should be.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor is not **null**, it's just **empty**. There's a huge difference.
SQLite doesn't allow for multiple commands on the same line.

This is why the semicolon (`;`) is totally useless.
The `INSERT` command after the `CREATE TABLE` one is simply **ignored**.

Use 2 separate `execSQL()` instructions on 2 separate SQL command strings, instead.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, Table is created successfully, only issue is with insertion.Use code like below to insert the data

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put("id", 1);
values.put("name", accueil);
values.put("display_name", Accueil);

long rowId=db.insert("TableName", null, values);

      if(rowId>0)
      {
        Log.d("TAG","Inserted Successfully");
      }
```